# TypeError: mergeImages is not a function

Tags: node.js

I am trying to use this package [merge-images](https://www.npmjs.com/package/merge-images) to layer images (that I currently have in a temp folder) on top of each other and display it on my localhost webpage.
This is my code:

```
const mergeImages = require('merge-images');
const { Canvas, Image } = require('canvas');


function MyImage() {

    
mergeImages([
    '../../../Temp/base/ffa3bb.png', 
    '../../../Temp/trait/blur/variant_1/8abfff.png', 
    '../../../Temp/trait/blur/variant_2/f8f88c.png',
    '../../../Temp/lines.png'],
    {
        Canvas: Canvas,
        Image: Image
    })
    .then(b64 => document.querySelector('img').src = b64);
    

  return (
     <img src={Image} />
  );
}
  
  export default MyImage;
```

And I'm getting this error:

```
TypeError: mergeImages is not a function
```

But when I go to the definition of mergeImages I see that it is a function:

```
declare function mergeImages(sources: mergeImages.ImageSource[], options?: mergeImages.Options): Promise<string>;
```

I am fairly confident I have no idea what I'm doing and my mistake is likely stupid, and I probably have other mistakes any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Make sure it's installed correctly. `npm install merge-images`. Delete and reinstall node-modules if that doesn't work.

Comment: deleted and reinstalled node-modules, still have the same error

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are importing an `es6` module, it might exported as `default`. The documentation uses `es6` as the example, and that implies it is exported as `default`.

```
import mergeImages from 'merge-images';
```

So you might try

```
const mergeImages = require('merge-images').default;
```

One way to be sure is to log the item right after importing it, then inspect in the console.

```
const mergeImages = require('merge-images')
console.log('mergeImages', mergeImages)
```